# spying function inside a function in a service, in controller test using jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

let the service be

```
function testService(){

  function test(){
        return{
              find:find,
              save:save
        };
        function find(){
              //return a promise
        }
        function save(){
              //some code
        }
  }

  return {test:test};
```

}

let the controller be

```
function TestController(testService){
  var ctrl=this;
  ctrl.first=first;

  function first(){
          testService.test().find().then(function(response){});
  }
```

}

how can i mock the the service call in the 'first' function in controller using jasmine

Answer (score 2):

Something like this...

setup

```
const testSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('testService.test', ['find', 'save'])
const testServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('testService', ['test'])
const reponse = {
    status: 200
}
testServiceSpy.test.and.returnValue(testSpy)
testSpy.find.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(response))
```

and in your test

```
const testController = new TestController(testServiceSpy)
testController.first()
expect(testServiceSpy.test).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(test.find).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spyOn(testService, 'test').and.callFake(function () {
        return { find: function () {
                return {
                    then: function (callback) {
                        return callback({ 'status': 3 }); }
                };
            }
        };

    });
```

ctrl.first();
expect(testService.test).toHaveBeenCalled();

i used this method and found working